# How to determine from outside of wordpress if a visitor is logged into Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Using php is it possible to determine if a visitor to my site is logged into the wordpress area of my site.

By this I mean the wordpress area of my site (which has registration) is in for example `example.com/members/`.

I would like to know from `example.com/offers.php` if they are logged into the wordpress area `example.com/members`.

Comment: I think this will help you : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105736/how-to-get-login-data-session-outside-wordpress

Comment: I am really struggling. I have tried everything I have found to try and get this to work without success. get_current_user_id(); always returns 0.
The issue seems to be that my wordpress is in the folder mydomain.com/members/
I want to access via php to  see if someone is logged in from a php routine in my public_html root (routine caled mydomain.com/offers.php)

Comment: I have found various articles saying that the issue is cookie related. Saying that I should add to my wp-config.php 
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH','/');
I added that right before /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
If I log out I then can't log back in again! 
I use the plugin Theme My Login to add login or logout onto my navigation menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK what seems to get overlooked is that when trying to access wordpress from a different folder to where wordpress is installed then using the following code does not work... is_user_logged_in() will always return false.

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); 
Include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/members/wp-load.php');
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {echo ' You are currently logged in.'. '<br />';}
else
{    echo ' You are currently not logged in.'. '<br />';}
?>
```

I managed to find a workaround that for me at least works.
I was building an html page that needed to test if the user was logged into the wordpress area on my site. So what I did was place the above test into a file that WAS in the wordpress folder. Then simply used an IFrame in my html that used as it's src= the file that was in the wordpress folder. That then echoes out what was need depending upon the user being logged in or logged out.

Probably a sloppy solution but at least it works.

Answer (score 4):

You can use WordPress functions outside too. Just include wp-load.php with your installation path.

use [get_currentuserinfo](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)() to get user data of logged in user.

```
// Include the wp-load'
include('YOUR_WP_PATH/wp-load.php');
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo(); // to get currently logged in user data
echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
}else{
   echo "User not logged in";
}
```